# Textarea Messing up Navigation

Tags: html, css

Alright so I'm redesigning a website to include some of the nifty HTML5 features but I've hit a roadblock that no matter what I try I can't seem to find out how to get rid of it.

The following is the code of the HTML5 page where the error is occurring

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Contact Us</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body id="contact">
        <header>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Signwrite Signs &amp; Designs Logo" /></a>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">What We Do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="content">
            <article>
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                <p>
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3173.5474529375374!2d144.9503499999996!3d-37.30585800436599!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x6ad7a4a8a3379d23%3A0x9d76c4464bec770c!2s106B+Powlett+St%2C+Kilmore+VIC+3764!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1429341803861" width="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0">&nbsp;</iframe>
                </p>
                <form method="POST" id="contact-form"> 
                    <p>
                        Full name<br>
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" value="" placeholder="Enter your full name here">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Email<br>
                        <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter your email here">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Query<br>
                        <textarea></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <button>Submit</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </article>
        </section>
        <footer>
            &copy; Signwrite Signs &amp; Designs 2015.
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The following is the code for the CSS file I use (I am referencing all the external sources I have gained help from, hence the comments)

```
/* http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp */
@font-face {
    font-family: Frutiger;
    src: url(frutiger.otf);
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 50px 0;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body#home { background-image: url(images/backgrounds/home-large.jpg); }
body#about { background-image: url(images/backgrounds/about-large.jpg); }
body#contact { background-image: url(images/backgrounds/contact-large.jpg); }

/* http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body#home { background-image: url(images/backgrounds/home-small.jpg); }
    body#about { background-image: url(images/backgrounds/about-small.jpg); }
    body#contact { background-image: url(images/backgrounds/contact-small.jpg); }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body#home { background-image: url(images/backgrounds/home-medium.jpg); }
    body#about { background-image: url(images/backgrounds/about-medium.jpg); }
    body#contact { background-image: url(images/backgrounds/contact-medium.jpg); }
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(20, 157, 234, 0.5), rgba(23, 10, 81, 0.5)); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(20, 157, 234, 0.5), rgba(23, 10, 81, 0.5)); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(20, 157, 234, 0.5), rgba(23, 10, 81, 0.5)); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(20, 157, 234, 0.5), rgba(23, 10, 81, 0.5)); /*Standard*/
}

header img {
    height: 100px;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
}

nav li {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li a {
    font-family: Frutiger;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(23, 10, 81, 1);
}

/* http://codeconvey.com/2014/04/12/make-css-sticky-footer/ */
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(23, 10, 81, 1);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    font-family: Frutiger;
}

/* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically */
#front {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

/* http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp 
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/ */
#front h1 {
    font-family: Frutiger;
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

/* http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp */
#button {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 154, 201, 1), rgba(233, 42, 142, 1)); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 154, 201, 1), rgba(233, 42, 142, 1)); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 154, 201, 1), rgba(233, 42, 142, 1)); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 154, 201, 1), rgba(233, 42, 142, 1)); /*Standard*/
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #4a1330;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#button a {
    background-color: #e92b8e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3%;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Frutiger;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

#button a:hover {
    background-color: #e864a8;
}

#content {
    font-family: Verdana;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    position: relative;
    left: 24.5%;
}

/* https://github.com/karlhorky/gray/blob/gh-pages/css/gray.css */
#signs a:hover, #screenprinting a:hover, #digital-printing a:hover, #printing a:hover {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    filter: grayscale(0);
}

#screenprinting a, #screenprinting a:hover { background-image: url(images/screenprinting.jpg); }
#digital-printing a, #digital-printing a:hover { background-image: url(images/digital-printing.jpg); }
#printing a, #printing a:hover { background-image: url(images/printing.jpg); }
#signs a, #signs a:hover { background-image: url(images/signs.jpg); }

#signs a, #screenprinting a, #digital-printing a, #printing a {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix type='saturate' values='0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
     filter: grayscale(1);
     filter: gray;
}

.service a {
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    margin-left: 2.4%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    line-height: 2200%; 
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#services:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

#contact-form input, #contact-form textarea {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px gray;
    width: 97%;
}

#contact-form button {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px gray;
}
```

Now when I enter all that code in and view it on Chrome 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit) in OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 the navigation bar drops almost the height of the header bar. I remove the textarea underneath Query and it magically appears back in place.

I have no idea what is going on and it's driving me insane! I feel I am missing something and would appreciate a fresh set of eyes on this problem.

Regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace the "p" with "div" element

can you look at this [Fiddle replaced p element  with div element](https://jsfiddle.net/alanmehio/bfepdvdh/)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Even when I remove all the p tags and replace with divs or nothing it still does it. The only thing I can seem to stop it dropping is removing the textarea or an input tag.

Comment: It is just guessing since I don't have similar environment as you ( Chrome 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit) in OSX Yosemite ) . I have found this  styling

Comment: It is just guessing since I don't have similar environment as you ( Chrome 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit) in OSX Yosemite ) . I have found this  styling `#font and #font h1` is not being used  since selector can't be found.  Just a hint, it  may be  there is a lack of vertical space which is caused by the extra height from textArea.  Hope this give you some hints